# Chat 'last message time' bug?

Tags: bug, chat

Take a look at the screenshot at the bottom of my post. Refreshing it solved the problem.

I have a faulty Wi-Fi card, so the connection could drop at some time. What is more, my OS clock is acting strange (I can't force BIOS, Linux and Windows to show the same time) - I am providing those facts so you can better identify the case.

I think '2 hours ago' could be somehow connected with the fact, that my clock is showing the time for another timezone than the one I am currently connected to, despite the fact that I asked Windows to detect TZ automatically.
[image]